# getEventArgs().getSaveMode() returns Undefined for Disqualify the Lead

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have been working with dynamics 365 v9.0 and facing the issue to get the required saveMode on Lead disqualification.

Please refer below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/save-event-arguments/getsavemode

As per the above link getEventArgs().getSaveMode() should returns 15 for disqualify. In version 8.2 I'm getting the 15 for disqualify as I should but in V9.0 It returns Undefined. Please refer below screenshot:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPRs6.png)

Does anybody help me on this problem?

Your suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: can you check if you have legacy form rendering enabled in system settings?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I checked off "Pass execution context as first parameter" in Handler Properties window, then pass 'executionContextObj' as the first parameter in handler such as onLoad(executionContextObj), onChange(executionContextObj), onSave(executionContextObj).

[image]